# Making connection to hardware using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a connection to hardware (a controller of a moving stage) from Physik Insrumente using MATLAB. However, I have tried using the code that the company provided but did not work, so I have simplified but still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
addpath ( 'C:\Users\Public\PI\PI_MATLAB_Driver_GCS2' );
Controller = PI_GCS_Controller();
controllerSerialNumber = '118011005';
C867 = Controller.ConnectUSB(controllerSerialNumber);
display(C867.qIDN())
```

I am getting this error message:

```matlab
PI_MATLAB_Driver_GCS2 loaded successfully.
Error using PI_GCS_Controller/ConnectUSB (line 17)
There is no interface or DLL handle with the given ID

Error in PI_GCS_Controller/ConnectUSB (line 17)
            error(szDesc);

Error in PI_GCS_Controller/subsref (line 46)
            varargout{1} = feval(fun,c,par{1});

Error in Untitled (line 5)
C867 = Controller.ConnectUSB(controllerSerialNumber);
```

`ConnectUSB` is:

```
function [c] = ConnectUSB(c,szIdentifier)
FunctionName = 'PI_ConnectUSB';
if(any(strcmp(FunctionName,c.dllfunctions)))
    if(nargin<2),    szIdentifier = blanks(5000); end,
    try
        [c.ID, szIdentifier] = calllib(c.libalias,FunctionName,szIdentifier);
        if(c.ID<0)
            iError = GetError(c);
            szDesc = TranslateError(c,iError);
            error(szDesc);
        end
    catch
        rethrow(lasterror);
    end
else
    error('%s not found',FunctionName);
end
```

How can I connect to this controller?

Comment: The error actually happens on the line `[c.ID, szIdentifier] = calllib(c.libalias,FunctionName,szIdentifier);`. You should have a look at the `calllib` function code and see in which condition(s) this error is thrown.